# How to add links to different picture areas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink

I want to know if it is possible to have one picture and make different links from different sections of the picture.

Here is the picture, I need to make links for the blocks and the rows:

[image: menu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible with imageMap. Google and read up on HTML ImageMap

[Image Map - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

[W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Comment: thanks. i found this very usefull http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/